# Modify arraystretch for a single row in table

Tags: tables, spacing

I need to display fractions within a table and it requires to set

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.3}
```

The problem is that not all rows contain fractions, and in this cases the white space below and above is too big. I can tweak it manually with something like `\\[-2ex]`. This works for the middle cases, though its a little inconvenient, but I have no idea how to reduce the absolute top space.

Something like

```
\vspace{-2ex}
```

has no effect.

The best would be to be able to change the arraystretch for a single table row, but the command has no effect after `\begin{tabular}`. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.3}

    \begin{tabular}{@{}c|l@{}}
            \bfseries $R_x$ & Symbol\\
            \hline\hline
            $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B} $\\
            $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B} $\\
            $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B} $\\
            \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

### MWE with siunitx

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{R}{8.5cm}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.3}

    \begin{tabular}{@{}Sc|Sl@{}}
            \bfseries $R_x$ & Symbol\\
            \hline\hline
            $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B} $\\
            some text & some other text \\
            $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B} $\\
            $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B} $\\
            \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best solution is to use the `cellspace` package: it defines an adjustable *minimal* vertical padding around a cell. For this, you have to prefix the column specifier with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`).

With `\arraystretch`, there are two drawbacks: first the cell contents is no more vertically centred, and second, you have to determine, by trial and error, the stretch value – any modification of the contents may result in a new value, as is demonstrated in the following, where I modified one fraction, keeping the value you gave:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, cellspace, hhline}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.3}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c|l@{}}
    \bfseries $R_x$ & Symbol \\
    \hline\hline
    $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B} $ \\
    \hline
    $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B + \cfrac{C}{D}} $ \\
    \hline
    $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B} $ \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\hskip2cm
  \begin{tabular}{@{}Sc|Sl@{}}
    \bfseries $R_x$ & Symbol \\
    \hline\hline
    $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B} $ \\
    \hline
    $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B + \cfrac{C}{D}} $ \\
    \hline
    $\dfrac{a}{b}$ & $ \dfrac{A}{B} $ \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered document]

Comment: There are weird things happening when `siunitx` is loaded (changing of layout or erros, depending on content of tabular. Can you check my other MWE? .. which according to google seems to be a known, but 5 year old problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, as your code didn't load `siunitx`: `S` is a column type defined by siunitx. The answer is in the siunitx manual: use `C` as a pre-specifier instead (`Cc, Cl, Cr`)

Comment: Now it works like a charm, thanks for letting me know about this great package. However as `siunitx` is such a heavy used package, you may should include your comment within your answer.

Comment: I'll do it. Note  `cellspace` doesn't work in all situations, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Similar result as with `cellspace` package, as propose Bernard, you can obtain with `makecell` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{makecell}% <-- for gaped cells

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{R}{8.5cm}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}|>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}@{}}
R_x                 &   \text{Symbol}           \\
    \hline\hline
\frac{a}{b}         &   \frac{A}{B}             \\
    \hline
\text{some text}    &   \text{some other text}  \\
    \hline
\frac{a}{b}         &   \frac{A}{B}             \\
    \hline
\frac{a}{b}         &   \frac{A}{B}             \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

*Note:*
Also `\makegapedcells` doesn't work in all circumstances. For example, it prevent coloring rows/columns with use `\colortbl` or `[table]{xcolor}` packages.