# Override table cell horizontal alignment with cellspace

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, cellspace

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{cellspace}                                                                                                                                                                                     
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{Sl Sl}
    a & \makecell{b}\\
    A & $\frac{1}{9}\times20$\\
    A & $\frac{1}{9}\times2000 + b$\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I use `\makecell` to override horizontal placement of a single cell. In the output I see that the mathematical formulae in different rows don't have enough space between them:

[image]

Following [Modify arraystretch for a single row in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302960/modify-arraystretch-for-a-single-row-in-table?answertab=active#tab-top) I use the `cellspace` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{Sl Sl}
    a & \makecell{b}\\
    A & $\frac{1}{9}\times20$\\
    A & $\frac{1}{9}\times2000 + b$\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Now the math formulae are spaced more comfortably, but the centring of a cell with `\makecell` got disrupted. How to fix this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\multicolumn` instead of `\makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{Sl Sl}
    a & \multicolumn{1}{Sc}{b}\\ 
    A & $\frac{1}{9}\times20$\\ 
    A & $\frac{1}{9}\times2000 + b$\\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]